# How to match just 1 or 2 chars with regex

Tags: java, regex

i want regx to match any word of 2 or 1 characters example ( is , an , or , if, a )

i tried this :-

```
int scount = 0;
String txt = "hello everyone this is just test aa ";
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("\\w{1,2}");
Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(txt);

while (m2.find()) {
    scount++;
}
```

but got wrong matches.

Comment: What does it mean 'nothing'? You should have some matches out there.

Comment: In fact your code matches every two or one letters. That is my output: he,ll,o,ev,er,yo,ne,th,is,is,ju,st,te,st,aa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to use [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("\\b\\w{1,2}\\b");
```

These anchors match at the start/end of alphanumeric "words", that is, in positions before a `\w` character if there is no `\w` character before that, or after a `\w` character if there is no `\w` character after that.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should be a bit more descriptive. Your current code [returns 15](http://ideone.com/yWtAyj) from the variable `scount`. That's not *nothing*.

If you want to get a count of the 2 letter words, and that is excluding underscores, digits within this count, I think that you would be better off with negative lookarounds:

```
Pattern.compile("(?i)(?<![a-z])[a-z]{1,2}(?![a-z])");
```

With a string input of `hello everyone this is just 1 test aa`, you get the value of `scount` as 2 (`is` and `aa`) and not 3 (`is`, `1`, `aa`) as you would have if you were looking for only 1 or 2 consecutive `\w`.

Also, with `hello everyone this is just test aa_`, you get a count of 1 with `\w` (`is`), but 2 (`is`, `aa`)with the lookarounds.